# Graph servicePrincipals API is not returning all the apps

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I created an application in Azure Portal and did set up single sign-on with SAML, it generated ObjectID and ApplicationId and its working without any issues w.r.t functionality.

Now when I try to get the list of apps using Graph API - Applications or ServicePrincipals APIs, the newly configured app is not listed in the response. Also I tried with Salesforce App but no luck. Can anyone suggest whether I have to refer different Graph API to get the SAML enabled apps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The app should be there when you use the [`List servicePrincipals`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/serviceprincipal-list?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) API, there may be some delay, please try again via the query below works for me, it list all the SAML enabled apps, also make sure you are running it in the correct AAD tenant.

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/servicePrincipals?$filter=preferredSingleSignOnMode eq 'saml'
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you @Joy Wang. I was also using the same. but unfortunately I am not getting the apps. I also tried with by adding request header ConsistencyLevel: eventual - Documentation for using this technique:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/serviceprincipal-list?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#example-4-use-search-to-get-service-principals-with-display-names-that-contain-the-letters-team-including-a-count-of-returned-objects

Comment: @KrishnaAnumothu Did you test it in the Graph explorer? If so, please make sure you have logged in the correct tenant, follow this https://stackoverflow.com/a/65573056/9455659

Comment: @KrishnaAnumothu And if you logged in the correct tenant, could you get other apps?

Comment: Yes I could able to get the data if I login with by passing the tenantId https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer?tenant=xxxxx. For the same user why it is not returning without the tenantId. Both the cases, the user is same. Appreciate your inputs

Comment: @KrishnaAnumothu Because the explorer will log in the user's home tenant by default. If my reply is helpful, please accept it as answer, thank you.

Comment: @KrishnaAnumothu Any other concerns about this issue?

Comment: Thank you @Joy Wang. Your suggestion worked. Mainly, we need to get the specific tenant user token to get the details of all the apps