# List users for a different Active Directory using Microsoft Graph

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, blazor, azure-ad-b2c

I am using the [Microsoft Graph Explorer](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer) to query the list of users. The account I am using for this query is an admin account that is a **member of multiple directories**.

**How can I control which directory to query using the Microsoft Graph API?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, sign-out the Graph Explorer if you already logged in, then hit `https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer?tenant=xxxxx`(`xxxxx` is the `tenant id`) or `https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer?tenant=tenantname.onmicrosoft.com`, login the account again, then you can list the users in the tenant you specify.